# Implementing multi-role access in Laravel and Jetstream

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-livewire, laravel-jetstream

I'm working on a school web app project using Laravel and Jetstream, which requires three different user roles: admin, instructor, and student. Each role should have a unique dashboard upon login. However, I'm unsure how to implement multiple authentication and routing for these roles. So far, I've installed Laravel and Jetstream but haven't made further progress. I've tried learning from YouTube tutorials but still find it challenging to start. Any expert guidance would be appreciated. Please note that English is not my first language.

Comment: Have you searched on here for anything similar?

Comment: Create a table for `roles` and an intermediate table to attach users to roles. Implement method on User model to check if user has specific role. Then when trying to authenticate use method `attempWhen` which you need to pass a function as second parameter that will let you authenticate if true is returned. Something ike: `Auth::attemptWhen($credentials, function (User $user) { return $user->isMember(); })`.  The `isMember` method would be something like: `public function isMember() { return $this->roles()->where('title', 'member')->exists();}`. That is one way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Redirect Using Auth Middleware:
In *app/Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php*, update the handle method as follows:

```
      public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
{
    $guards = empty($guards) ? [null] : $guards;

    foreach ($guards as $guard) {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            $user = Auth::user();

            if ($user->isAdmin()) {
                return redirect('/admin_panel');
            } elseif ($user->isEditor()) {
                return redirect('/editor_panel');
            } elseif ($user->isUser()) {
                return redirect('/user_panel');
            }
        }
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

After following these steps, users will be redirected to the relevant dashboard according to their roles after logging in. Note, however, that you may need to adjust the user roles and which dashboard they should be redirected to according to your application.

Comment: This means I have to create migration, model, and controller of the user roles first right? As well as creating their respective routes and views?

Comment: Yes, you have to create them.